# How to save the logs generated using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using web-driver 2.20 and created the automation suit. Unlike 
selenium RC (get_log function) i can't figure out the command to save 
the logs generated. 
I have tried :

```
FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();   
p.setPreference("webdriver.log .file", "/tmp/firefox_console"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
```

but can't find the python equivalent. 
Also http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/sel... 
this is also in java. Also I saw "import logging" function don't know 
how to save the logs in a file using it. 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will do the same for you. There is no internal logs for the python code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

p = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()   
p.set_preference("webdriver.log.file", "/tmp/firefox_console")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks it worked after setting:

```
p.set_preference("webdriver.log.file", "/tmp/firefox_console")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
logfile = 'logs' + os.sep + ((__file__.upper())[(__file__.rfind(os.sep)+1):]).replace('.PY', '.log')
logging.basicConfig(format= '%(asctime)-12s [%(filename)-10s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', filename=logfile, filemode='w', level=logging.INFO)
```

will create a logfile at your project workspace which you can work on